# Converting Reactive Cocoa doNext^ to Swift

Tags: objective-c, closures, block, swift, reactive-cocoa

I have the following Obj-C method:

```
- (RACSignal *)updateCurrentConditions {
    return [[self.client fetchCurrent:self.coordinate] doNext:^(WXCondition *condition) {
        self.currentCondition = condition;
    }];
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to convert it into Swift, except I'm not sure how to return it properly.

How would I go about doing:

`[[self.client fetchCurrent:self.coordinate] doNext:^(WXCondition *condition) {}];`?

```
func updateCurrentConditions() -> RACSignal {
    return client.fetchCurrent(coordinate: coordinate) {
        currentCondition = condition
    }
}
```

Here is a link to [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/DesignGuidelines.md) and information regarding `-doNext:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
func updateCurrentConditions() -> RACSignal {
  let fetchSignal = client.fetchCurrent(coordinate: coordinate)
  return fetchSignal.doNext(block: {condition: WXCondition? -> Void in
    let wxCondition = condition as WXCondition
    currentCondition = wxCondition
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fetchCurrent method returns a RACSignal. Also, doNext takes an `id` as the method parameter, so I am guessing you will need to cast:

```
func updateCurrentConditions() -> RACSignal {
    let fetchSignal = client.fetchCurrent(coordinate: coordinate)
    return fetchSignal.doNext(condition) {
        let wxCondition = condition as WXCondition
        currentCondition = wxCondition
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like the right way to go, however where's `condition`?

Comment: Also, `doNext` isn't a member of `RACSignal` so I don't see that working properly either.

Comment: Are you seeing my comments ?